# CNN - What is every single kernels of the second conv-layer exactly convoluted with?

Tags: python, input, convolution

I'm a student in acoustics and really new at deep learning. My goal is to get a good understanding in how a CNN exactly works. There is one part that I don't understand. I can't find any precise information about that.

My model is something like this:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape = input_shape)) 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(48, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')) 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(ndim, activation='relu', use_bias=True, batch_size=batchSize, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=None))       
    model.add(Dense(nclasses, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-2))) 

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

It works, that's not the problem. I know, that the input of second conv-layer consists of 32 feature maps (output of first pooling-layer).

**What is every single kernels of the second conv-layer exactly convoluted with?**

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge, if your input image is `M*N`, then the output for the first Conv2D is `M*N` with depth 32, that is `M*N*32`. And `(M/2)*(N/2)*32` after the   first max pooling. So the input for the second Conv2D is the `(M/2)*(N/2)*32` matrix (tensor). Then the second Conv2D convolution the 32 `(M/2)*(N/2)` 2D matrix (tensor) to `(M/2)*(N/2) * 64` matrix.

To specify how the convolution behave. I used tensorflow for deep learning, the statement below will also help you understand CNN.

Input image size [M, N, 3], 3 for image deepth (RGB for example), with this size of image the first convolution should have size [3, 3, 3, 32], first two 3s for convolution window size, the third 3 for the depth, 32 for output depth as your example. Then to do a second convolution should have size [3, 3, 32, 64], the third number 32 must be the same as the first conv output depth.

For this we can see, convolution is done with multiply 3*3 windows, that is one depth to one convolution window. In your example, the second conv should have 3*3*32 parameters to conv your M*N*32 output from the first conv.

Hope this is what you want and that I have state it clearly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answering. I'm exactly with you exept the last sentence. I think the output of the second conv-layer corresponds to the number of kernels of the second conv-layer (here: 48). But my question aimed something different. How many convolutions are computed in the second conv-layer? And which kernel of the second conv-layer is convoluted with wich part of the output of the first pooling layer?

Comment: I modified the answer, check if it is what you expect.